# Odoo Pass Value During Create

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

In this code below :

```
<field name="fields_example" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_quick_create': True}" context="{'default_next_field' : fields_example}" />
```

I want to pass any text that user wrote. For example, the same functionality can be found on almost all odoo modules. in this case, i'm going to use `res.partner` as example. I am create and edit this "Example Customer" here

[image]

After that, the value are being passed on into the pop up

[image]

Using `context="{'default_next_field' : fields_example}"` works. however, it does work only if the value is already defined in the current record. in my case, it is still on the fly.

How to make it possible?